# How to use rsync on LTFS (Linear Tape File System)

Tags: backup, rsync

I'm trying to set up a simple backup solution using LTFS and backintime (which uses rsync). The first backup works fine. Rsync writes all files to the tape. However, when I try to update the backup, the tape starts hunting around and performance gets horrible.

If I mount ltfs with `-o syslogtrace`, I can see what ltfs is doing in the syslog:

```
Backend readpos: (1, 2296175) FM = 10
FUSE release file 
FUSE set times 
FUSE chmod 
FUSE rename 
FUSE create file 
Backend locate: (1, 63137) 
FUSE chmod 
Backend readpos: (1, 63137) FM = 6 
Backend locate: (1, 2296176) 
Backend readpos: (1, 2296176) FM = 10 
FUSE flush 
Backend locate: (1, 63138)
```

I'd interpret this as rsync reading from two locations simulataneously.

Why is rsync reading at all? It should be writing! How can I prevent the tape from hunting around?

The command used for rsync without includes and excludes to make it more readable:

`sync --recursive --times --devices --specials --hard-links --human-readable --links --perms --executability --group --owner --info=progress2 --no-inc-recursive --whole-file --delete --delete-excluded -v -i --out-format=BACKINTIME: %i %n%L --link-dest=../../20230114-102905-656/backup --chmod=Du+wx / /media/tape/5/new_snapshot/backup`